# glossaries doesn't trigger page break and acronyms doesn't work

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra

I am having a bit of a problem with the acronym and glossaries-extra packages. It seems that my defined \newglossarystyle seems to be the problem but I can't figure out why. The first problem is that there is no acronympage generated despite the fact that I have acronyms declared in my preamble and \glsaddall used before \printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=Acronyms] in my main.
The second problem is that my glossary doesn't trigger a page break despite it being way too long. Also there is some weird stuff happening where there is a blank page between acronyms and my glossary.

Code (preamble):

```
  \usepackage[acronym,toc,nonumberlist,nogroupskip,nopostdot]{glossaries-extra} 
\GlsSetQuote{+}
\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{syi}{syo}{Symbolverzeichnis}
\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\makeglossaries[\acronymtype]

\newacronym{esvd}{ESVD}{Enhanced SVD}
\newacronym{ekf}{EKF}{Extended Kalman Filter}
\newacronym{eci}{ECI}{Earth Centered Inertial}

\glsnoexpandfields
\newglossaryentry{s:A}{name={$\underline{\underline{_{B}^{S}\textrm{A}_{Sun}}}$},description={Drehmatrix des Sensors},unit={\si{}},type={symbols}}
\newglossaryentry{s:ac}{name={\(a_{c}\)},description={Coriolisbeschleunigung},unit={m/$s^{2}$},type={symbols}}
\newglossaryentry{s:Babc}{name={\(\underline{_{}^{B}\textrm{a}_{Sun}}\), \(\underline{_{}^{B}\textrm{b}_{Sun}}\), \(\underline{_{}^{B}\textrm{c}_{Sun}}\)},description={Hilfsvektoren zur Ermittlung der Rotationsmatrix im satellitenfesten Koordinatensystem},unit={\si{}},type={symbols}}
\newglossaryentry{s:Sabc}{name={\(\underline{_{}^{S}\textrm{a}_{Sun}}\), \(\underline{_{}^{S}\textrm{b}_{Sun}}\), \(\underline{_{}^{S}\textrm{c}_{Sun}}\)},description={Hilfsvektoren zur Ermittlung der Rotationsmatrix im Sensorkoordinatensystem},unit={\si{}},type={symbols}}
.
.
.

\newglossarystyle{stylesymbols}{%
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{
  \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}p{0.7\linewidth}l} % Spaltenbreiten
  %\toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Formelzeichen}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Bedeutung}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Einheit}} \\
  \midrule
  }%
  {\end{tabular}}%
%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}% Header already set
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
& \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
& \glsunit{##1}  \tabularnewline
}
}
```

And in main:

```
\begin{document}
.
.
.
\tableofcontents
\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis]


%
\printnoidxglossary[sort=def,type=symbols,style=stylesymbols,nonumberlist]
```

And this code leads to this:
[image]

[image]

I am really frustrated by now and even after reading the "The glossaries package: a guide for beginners" file I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  What document class are you using?  If it is not for a book or report, indexes, glossaries and the like won't start on new pages.  An article class will treat them like a section.

Comment: In your glossary style for the list of symbols, you used tabular which itself can not break across pages. Use longtable instead of tabular. Your list of symbols also seems to be wider than the textwidth. In order to make sure the table breaks across pages and is narrow enough to fit into the textwidth, give xltabular instead of tabular a try.